# Swift Realm - unsafe mutable Accessor

Tags: swift, realm

New to Realm. I tinkered a bit around, made some Models, played with some test data, now i updated my Models (added some properties, removed some others, changed some existing) and want to completely delete my realms file so I can start from new with new testdata based on the new models. Somehow, i can't just delete the file.

1. Simply using

   try! realm.write {
    realm.deleteAll()
   }

crashes in `realm.unsafeMutableAddressor` on the line `let realm = try! Realm()`

2. Trying to delete everything via the Realm Browser, i can't find any button to delete the whole schema? I can only delete certain objects..
3. Trying to delete it via:

   try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: realm.configuration.fileURL!)

again crashes in the same error message as 1.

What the hell do I need to do in order to just "start from scratch"? This has cost me about an hour now, trying it in those 3 different ways. Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: I don't really know what code to post to give you any material to guess. What should i post for more helpful information about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're changing the schema around and don't want to worry about performing Realm migrations yet, it's not enough to simply delete all the objects in the Realm; you need to delete the Realm file from disk and start again.

If you're going to delete a Realm file, you need to do it before you call `Realm()` for the first time, since Realm will subsequently keep a copy of that instance in memory after that point (This can be mitigated by placing that instance creation inside an `@autoreleasepool` block though).

For debugging purposes, the easiest way to delete a Realm each time a migration is needed is to set `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` to `true` in the Realm's `Configuration` object.

```
var configuration = Realm.Configuration()
configuration.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded = true
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = configuration

let realm = try! Realm()
```

If you want to explicitly delete the default Realm file yourself, you need to do so by directly referencing the file URL in the default configuration. If you create a `Realm()` instance and then pull the `fileURL` property from that, it'll already be too late.

```
var configuration = Realm.Configuration()
let defaultURL = configuration.fileURL

try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: defaultURL)

let realm = try! Realm()
```

Let me know if you need any clarification on these points. Thanks for trying out Realm! :)